# Kernel Configuration for CAN-Bus

Tags: kernel, raspi-config, spi

I'm trying to configure my can-bus module. I'm following these [steps](http://elinux.org/RPi_CANBus) .

My branch is 3.18.y-rebase (from github)

When I came to device drivers->spi support step I couldn't see BCM2798 SPI controller driver (SPI0) option.

Resultant options are,

***SPI Master Controller Driver***

- Altera SPI controller(NEW)
- Utilities for bitbanging SPI masters(NEW)
- Cadence SPI controller(NEW)
- Freescale SPI controller and aeroflex gaisler grlib GPI controller
- Rockchip SPI controller common module(NEW)
- Xilinx SPI controller core support(NEW)
- DesignWare SPI controller core support(NEW)

***SPI Protocol Masters***

- Usermode SPI device driver support (NEW)
- Infinean TLE62X0 (for power switching)(NEW)

How can I choose BCM2798 driver?

Comment: I'm not familiar with CAN but isn't BCM2798 a typo for BCM2708?

Comment: also I'm beginner for CAN, i follow steps in this website (http://elinux.org/RPi_CANBus) and wrote there BCM2798. I guess it is a typo because in next steps it was BCM2708. Anyway i coundnt find this driver in kernel configuration. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in /proc/config.gz for the options used to build the (running) Raspberry Pi kernel.

E.g.

```
cd
cp /proc/config.gz .
gunzip config.gz
grep _SPI_ config
```

This produces

```
# CONFIG_SCSI_SPI_ATTRS is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_SPI_MASTER=y
# CONFIG_SPI_ALTERA is not set
CONFIG_SPI_BCM2835=m
CONFIG_SPI_BCM2708=m
# CONFIG_SPI_BITBANG is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_CADENCE is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_GPIO is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_FSL_SPI is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_OC_TINY is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_PL022 is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_PXA2XX_PCI is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_ROCKCHIP is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_SC18IS602 is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_XCOMM is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_XILINX is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_DESIGNWARE is not set
CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV=y
# CONFIG_SPI_TLE62X0 is not set
```

You can see that the needed settings are

```
CONFIG_SPI_MASTER=y
CONFIG_SPI_BCM2835=m
CONFIG_SPI_BCM2708=m
CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV=y
```

Comment: 3 of them are set except CONFIG_SPI_BCM2835 in my system

Comment: I don't know how these modules interact.  The bcm2835 is the Pi's System On a Chip (SOC), it contains the peripherals (SPI/I2C/gpios etc.), ARM CPU, and GPU.

Comment: While tweaking the config this way *might* work in this specific case, and probably is harmless to try, note that in general this often may not work; kernel options are inter-related and just hacking one into the .config will not set whatever it may depend on, etc.  As it says at the top, "Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT".  Again, though, it is *probably* harmless enough to try (unless you are working on the pi itself and two or three hours leading to a failed compilation = pain).

Answer (score 1):

In order to be valid, some kernel options first require other options be set, which is why you may not find them in `menuconfig`.  To figure out what the prerequisites are, you need the option `CONFIG_` tag name.  You can then search for it in menuconfig by pressing <kbd>/</kbd>.  Searching for `SPI_BCM2708` in the 3.18.6 kernel shows:

```
Symbol: SPI_BCM2708 [=n]
 Type  : tristateg20
 Prompt: BCM2708 SPI controller driver (SPI0)
 Location:
    -> Device Drivers
 (1)   -> SPI support (SPI [=n])
   Defined at drivers/spi/Kconfig:89
   Depends on: SPI [=n] && SPI_MASTER [=n] && (MACH_BCM2708 [=n]  MACH_BCM2709 [=y])
```

Right now, if I go into "Device Drivers" I will not see this option.  First I have to enable "SPI support", which activates the first two above.  Then, since `MACH_BCM2709` is enabled (this is actually ARMv7 for the pi 2; for earlier pi's it would have been `MACH_BCM2708`), I can go into the submenu and find both

- BCM2835 SPI controller
- BCM2708 SPI controller driver

You can similarly look at `SPI_BCM2835` via `/`.

`MACH_BCM2709` (or `08`) is automatically selected by `ARCH_BCM2709`, which requires a bunch of other stuff; you can look at them by `/` searching for the latter, but those presumably *should* have been set by using the `.config` from that elinux page.  If not, try `make clean`, `make bcmrpi_defconfig`, `make menuconfig`.

Note **that presumes you've set environment variables** for your cross-compiler (e.g. `export ARCH=arm`), if you are not doing it on the pi itself.   That must be done for menuconfig, not just the actual build.